# How do I create a while-loop in python with showing a random object from my list?

Tags: python, while-loop

So I have the following task:

First generate a list with strings of fictitious names for image files (e.g.my_list['image1.png','image2.png','image3.png']). Then write a while loop in which an image is randomly drawn from the list and presented until the number 1 or 2 is pressed. Instead of presenting an actual image, just use the print command (e.g. print ('image1.png') - you'll learn how to present images via PsychoPy later). First define the subject's response as a boolean (response = False). Instead of registering a response via keyboard or mouse, use the library random with its function randint to generate a random response. Finally, add an abort signal to interrupt the loop after a maximum of 20 repetitions if no response has been registered yet. Additionally, the names of the randomly drawn "images" should be cached according to their presentation and finally overwritten into a text file (.csv, or .tsv etc.) so that the order in which they were drawn is preserved.

The coding I have already done is the following, but if I try to start the operation nothing happens. There is no result.

```
from random import randint
from random import choice
 
imagefiles = ["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png"]
if 1 or 2:
    response = True
else:
    response = False
tries = 1
while tries <= 20:
    if response == False:
        print(random.choice(imagefiles))
        break 
    tries = tries + 1
```

Comment: `response = randint(1,10) in (1,2)` might be helpfull - if you put that into the loop you get a "random" value that is True or False - now you just need a counter to break from your loop if you get 20 times some random value > 2.

Answer (score 0):

your if statement

```
if 1 or 2:
```

will always be true. So your response will always be true.
Also when printing, you don't want to use random.choice only choice(), as you've already imported it this way.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `1 or 2` it's always `True` so you never get to print.

You should compare a variable to them instead, meaning: `if var in (1,2)` or `if var == 1 or var == 2`